# Missing Custom Post Type Metadata

Tags: custom-post-types

I've created a custom post type with CPTUI and am trying to get the post-metadata to appear the same as on the front page.   However, the post-metadata is not appearing, as if is missing.

the test site is http://50.87.248.66/~tulalipl/
the page with the custom type is http://50.87.248.66/~tulalipl/natosha-gobin/

The php to call the data is...

```
  <?php
    $post = array( 'post_type' => 'ngobin', 'posts_per_page' => '5'  );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $post );   
  ?>

     <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php
            if ( is_single() ) {
                the_title( '<h3 class="entry-title">', '</h3>' );
            } else {
                the_title( '<h3 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h3>' );
            }
    if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ): ?>
            <div class="post-details">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i><?php the_author(); ?>
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <time><?php the_time('m/j/y g:i A'); ?></time>
                <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> <?php the_category(', ' ) ?>
                <i class="fa fa-tags"></i> <?php the_tags(); ?>
                <div class="post-comments-badge"><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i><?php comments_number( 0, 1, '%' ); ?></a>
                </div> <!-- post-comments-badge-->
                  <?php edit_post_link( 'Edit', '<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>', '' ); ?>
                </div>



    <?php
        endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail () ) {  // check for feature image ?>
        <div class="post-image">
              <?php the_post_thumbnail ();?>
        </div> <!-- ================ End Post Image ================= -->
        <?php } ?>
    <div class="post-excerpt">
        <?php if (is_single()) { 
        the_content(); 
        } else {
            the_excerpt();
        } ?>
    </div><!-- ================  End Post Excerpt  ================= -->

    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <?php the_language_of_puget_sound_entry_footer(); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
</article><!-- #post-## -->


    <?php endwhile;  // end of the loop ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template code is checking to see if the post type is `post`, and only displaying the post meta information if that is `true`:

```
if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ): ?>
```

Since the custom post type `ngobin` is being viewed, the above check returns `false` so the meta data is not displayed. The fix is as simple; change the post type check to `ngobin`:

```
if ( 'ngobin' === get_post_type() ): ?>
        <div class="post-details">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i><?php the_author(); ?>
            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <time><?php the_time('m/j/y g:i A'); ?></time>
            <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> <?php the_category(', ' ) ?>
            <i class="fa fa-tags"></i> <?php the_tags(); ?>
            <div class="post-comments-badge"><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i><?php comments_number( 0, 1, '%' ); ?></a>
            </div> <!-- post-comments-badge-->
              <?php edit_post_link( 'Edit', '<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>', '' ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```